# Wired connection keeps disconnecting

Tags: wired, ifconfig

The wired connection to a Netgear DS104 hub keeps disconnecting.

It has never been able to maintain connection on this system. I have never run this hub on unix but it functions without issue on windows.

1. Please specify logging and configuration packages relevant to linux networking.
2. Please specify a solution to maintaining a connection

   ```
   dmesg | tail; lsb_release -a; uname -a
   [   85.217906] type=1400 audit(1383697555.735:39): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=2836 comm="mission-control" pid=2836 comm="mission-control" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
   [  302.485594] type=1400 audit(1383697772.613:40): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1236 comm="cupsd" pid=1236 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
   [  398.886608] type=1400 audit(1383697869.046:41): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1236 comm="cupsd" pid=1236 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
   [  422.615523] type=1400 audit(1383697892.782:42): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=3799 profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=3800 comm="mission-control" pid=3800 comm="mission-control" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
   [ 1249.187062] type=1400 audit(1383698719.628:43): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1236 comm="cupsd" pid=1236 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
   [25182.283648] postgres (17302): /proc/17302/oom_adj is deprecated, please use /proc/17302/oom_score_adj instead.
   [73672.207532] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up
   [73672.207553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
   [80034.553476] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link down
   [80107.283453] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: link up
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
   Release:    12.04
   Codename:   precise
   Linux Inspiron-3521-ub 3.8.0-32-generic #47~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 16:19:35 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

   ifconfig
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:86:7a:0f:07:67  
     inet6 addr: fe80::7686:7aff:fe0f:767/64 Scope:Link
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
     RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:2351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
     RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:533433 (533.4 KB)
   ```

Comment: It would appear that is notifies with disconnections until you manually assign an ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a DHCP server/router with DHCP on connected to the hub?  Is the machine a dual boot with windows?  If this isn't dual boot then check your ports on the hub or the port on the machine itself.  Then there is always the drivers to check.  Do you use wireless while connected with ethernet? If so I THINK that ethernet will automatically turn off if wireless is on, but I don't remember which version of Ubuntu this changed on. Just some things to look at if you didn't already.